# Understanding the class shared pointers and its use in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, shared-ptr

I am having difficulty understanding the piece of code given below.

```
class Child1 : public Base1 {
public:
    int Func1(char *Var);
}

class Cls_X: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Cls_X> {
public:
    void Func2(char *Var_copy);
}
```

`Func2` is called from `Func1` as below

```
int Func1(char * Var){
    ...
    make_shared<Cls_X>(ioc, ctx)->Func2(Varcopy_ptr);
    ...
}
```

**Questions:**

- How `class Cls_X: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Cls_X>` works?
  *Tried googling but couldn't understand the documentation for this, Can someone explain in simple english?*
- Are Cls_X and Child1 both derived class of Base1 here?

**NOTE:**

**The tag [boost] is added because the [code example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async/websocket_client_async.cpp) is taken from one of the boost libraries. Please check the example to see how `shared_from_this` is used in the program**

***Ps 1:-*** Change the suitable title if possible.

Comment: To know about it you must first know about the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (or CRTP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: Also, for the simple case showed here, I don't see any reason to use either `std::enable_shared_from_this` nor shared pointers (or any kind of pointers) at all. Why not just do `Cls_X(ioc, ctx).Func2(Varcopy_ptr);`? And considering the transient and temporary nature of the object created, do `Cls_X` need to be a class at all? Couldn't `Func2` be a non-member function instead? Possibly with `ioc` and `ctx` as extra arguments?

Comment: your example is not really demonstrating the use. `enable_shared_from_this` is as the name suggests to get a shared pointer from `this`. Your example would work without inheriting from `enable_shared_from_this`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually the post is deliberately made to look simple and focus on (my) confusion. For reference I have added the link to almost similar code in **Ps 1**. Which would answer your doubt "do Cls_X need to be a class at all". I am going through the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: I suggest you to reformulate the quesiton, because as it stands now you can safely ignore the fact that `Cls_X` inherits from `enable_shared_from_this`, it is not really necessary to understand the code snippet, while I have the feeling this is what you actually want to ask about

Comment: `Cls_X` is not derived from `Base1`. They're completely unrelated.

Comment: How `std::enable_shared_from_this` works is not really important. What's important is what it does and why you might want to use it. Is that what you wanted to ask?

Comment: @john Yes, I am actually not sure what happens at that particular line , which is why I asked "how it works". Possibly "What it does and why to use" better suits my situation here. :)

Comment: As mentioned, using [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this) is really only needed if you want to create a shared pointer from `this`, that is from inside a member function. It's is *not* needed to make a shared pointer in general.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the clarification :) I intuited that, but My confusion was to see that the way it is written, kind of looks similar to how a class is derived from a base class. I was confused if that too is happening here?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what happens, your class `Cls_X` inherits from the base class `std::enable_shared_from_this<Cls_X>`. And for how the recursion works, see the link in my first comment.

Comment: Hopefully, in the code not shown, there is some usage of `shared_from_this` in `Cls_X`. If that is the case, it looks like the author is being disciplined with only constructing `Cls_X` instances owned by `std::shared_ptr<Cls_X>`

Comment: @Caleth Yes! the _`shared from this`_ is used inside the `Cls_X`. Please [see this link](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/example/websocket/client/async/websocket_client_async.cpp) to see how it is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How `class Cls_X: public std::enable_shared_from_this<Cls_X>` works?

It can work *iff* the specialization of the template class (here `std::enable_shared_from_this<Cls_X>`) does not need to receive a type parameter  (here `Cls_X`) that is a complete type.

```
template <typename T>
struct has_a_member { T mem; };

template <typename T>
struct has_a_pointer { T *ptr; };

struct A : has_a_member<A> // error at this point: 
                           // A is incomplete at this point
                           // the definition of has_a_member<A> cannot be instantiated 
{
};

struct B : has_a_pointer<B> // OK, B is incomplete 
                            // still has_a_pointer<B> can be instantiated
{
};
```

And `enable_shared_from_this` is designed to work in that case, by expecting an incomplete type.